# Hazelcast Serialization Issue

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast cluster. It has serialised data stored in it, Java objects of a class implementing `Serializable`. This class does NOT have a `serialVersionUUID`. The structure of the class has changed, the data in Hazelcast cannot be deserialised any more.

Aside from reverting the changes (not an option) or flushing Hazelcast (not ideal) are there anyways to save the data safely?

Comment: Implement Externalizable interface and customize your serialization process.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out chapter 9 in the book of Hazelcast (https://hazelcast.com/resources/mastering-hazelcast/) which deals with serialization.